# Powershell LastWriteTime

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to test for old files in a synchronized folder, and send a text message if a file is older than 2 hours (this would mean that a file failed to update). I haven't included the "texting" part, because that works fine.

When I run my script I get three date:times for many of the files. Why do I get three values for the "last" writetime? And, how do I only look at the most recent "last" writetime?

Here's my script...

```
$Store = “ALI”, “COR”, “ELD”, “GRY”, “HML”, “JB”, “SWN”, “LBT”, “LGC”, “MAU”, “MID”, “MPW”, “RKE”, “SPC”, “SSP”, “TWL”, “WRD”
foreach ($element in $Store) 
{
$FPath = "E:\ServerFolders\SData\$element\$element-Cmp"
$FPath = $FPath.Replace("-", "_")
if(Get-Childitem $FPath  | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).addHours(-2) })
{
$FName = Get-ChildItem $FPath -name -Filter "*.7Z"
$FTime = (Get-ChildItem $FPath).LastWriteTime

$FName
$FTime
}}
```

Here's my output...

```
TX029.7Z
Wednesday, September 13, 2017 11:44:54 AM
Monday, November 13, 2017 8:01:34 PM
Monday, November 13, 2017 7:45:45 PM
TX059.7Z
Tuesday, August 22, 2017 7:56:18 PM
Monday, November 13, 2017 8:03:56 PM
Monday, November 13, 2017 8:41:05 PM
TX013.7Z
Monday, November 13, 2017 8:01:33 PM
Monday, November 13, 2017 7:33:20 PM
Friday, November 10, 2017 2:38:20 PM
TX050.7z
Monday, November 13, 2017 8:02:17 PM
Monday, November 13, 2017 9:46:19 AM
Tuesday, October 31, 2017 7:46:01 AM
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

I ran the code that Stephen suggested. I am still getting multiple values for LastWriteTime for many of my files.

This is the resultant output on 11/24/17 at 8:57 AM, when all files show a timestamp in a dir of approximately 8:46 AM or so.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Store = “ALI”, “COR”, “ELD”, “GRY”, “HML”, “JB”, “SWN”, “LBT”, “LGC”, “MAU”, “MID”, “MPW”, “RKE”, “SPC”, “SSP”, “TWL”, “WRD”
foreach ($element in $Store) 
{
    $FPath = "E:\ServerFolders\SData\$element\$element-Cmp"
    $FPath = $FPath.Replace("-", "_")
    #this if statement does not return a true / false value
    #PowerShell is using whether an object is returned by Get-ChildItem
    # or not to try and determine a boolean value
    if(Get-Childitem $FPath  | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).addHours(-2) })
{
#at this point all we know is that some file exists with a write time
#of more than 2 hours but it could be any file

#You then get the name but only of all *.7z files in the path
#but there's no guarantee that this is the file you need
$FName = Get-ChildItem $FPath -name -Filter "*.7Z"

#This line gets the lastwritetime for all files in the folder
#regardless of the lastwritetime of the file
$FTime = (Get-ChildItem $FPath).LastWriteTime

$FName
$FTime
}}
TX025.7Z

Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:04:20 AM
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:46:54 AM
TX029.7Z
Wednesday, September 13, 2017 11:44:54 AM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:01:26 AM
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:45:45 AM
TX049.7Z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:03:18 AM
Wednesday, November 22, 2017 5:46:02 PM
GA007.7Z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 7:45:38 PM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:02:20 AM
GA004.7Z
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:47:01 AM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:30:53 AM
GA003.7Z
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:47:10 AM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 10:30:48 AM
MO001.7Z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:04:45 AM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 7:47:08 PM
TX059.7Z
Tuesday, August 22, 2017 7:56:18 PM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:03:48 AM
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:41:02 AM
AR001.7Z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 7:46:02 PM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:05:08 AM
TX013.7Z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:01:25 AM
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:34:11 AM
TX050.7z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:02:03 AM
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:46:19 AM
TX024.7Z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:03:48 AM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 8:40:36 PM
GA010.7Z
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:45:24 AM
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:02:39 AM
TX002.7Z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:02:03 AM
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:43:45 AM
TX035.7Z
Thursday, November 23, 2017 11:03:17 AM
Friday, November 24, 2017 8:51:39 AM



PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem $FPath).LastWriteTime` should probably be `(Get-ChildItem $FName.FullName).LastWriteTime`

Comment: Have you tried piping $FTime to "Get-Member"? Also, try putting breakpoints in your code, specifically where you are setting your $FTime variable, so you can see what is going on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overly complicating the process. You can simply add a select-object to grab the 2 properties you want.

```
$Store = “ALI”, “COR”, “ELD”, “GRY”, “HML”, “JB”, “SWN”, “LBT”, “LGC”, “MAU”, “MID”, “MPW”, “RKE”, “SPC”, “SSP”, “TWL”, “WRD”
foreach ($element in $Store)
{
    $FPath = "E:\ServerFolders\SData\$element\$element-Cmp"
    $FPath = $FPath.Replace("-", "_")
    #Filter for *.7z, with a lastwritetime older than 2 hours
    #Grab only the name and lastwritetime
    Get-Childitem $FPath -Filter "*.7z" |
        Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).addHours(-2) } |
        Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime
}
```

EDIT: Explaining the logic of the original process

```
$Store = “ALI”, “COR”, “ELD”, “GRY”, “HML”, “JB”, “SWN”, “LBT”, “LGC”, “MAU”, “MID”, “MPW”, “RKE”, “SPC”, “SSP”, “TWL”, “WRD”
foreach ($element in $Store) 
{
    $FPath = "E:\ServerFolders\SData\$element\$element-Cmp"
    $FPath = $FPath.Replace("-", "_")
    #this if statement does not return a true / false value
    #PowerShell is using whether an object is returned by Get-ChildItem
    # or not to try and determine a boolean value
    if(Get-Childitem $FPath  | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).addHours(-2) })
{
#at this point all we know is that some file exists with a write time
#of more than 2 hours but it could be any file

#You then get the name but only of all *.7z files in the path
#but there's no guarantee that this is the file you need
$FName = Get-ChildItem $FPath -name -Filter "*.7Z"

#This line gets the lastwritetime for all files in the folder
#regardless of the lastwritetime of the file
$FTime = (Get-ChildItem $FPath).LastWriteTime

$FName
$FTime
}}
```

Without seeing the original file structure its hard to tell exactly what you are working with but the above should explain why you are getting multiple lastwritetime values in your script.

Comment: This solved one problem, but not the whole problem.... In the original output shown above, each file had three LastWriteTime values. And some of those values were 1 or 2 months ago? The actual, or correct, most recent time shown is the value that displays if you "dir". Using the solution that StephenP provided displays only one time. But when using this as a test, it is apparently still seeing the values from many days earlier. Every single file "fails" the test and sends a text message saying the file is over 2 hours old. The actual age of the file is 15 minutes old. Why is this happening?

Comment: I just updated the answer to explain the logic behind why you are seeing multiple lastwritetime values in your original script. If the message sending portion isn't working as expected, open a question for that portion as well.

Comment: Hi Stephen, the message-sending portion is working without a problem. There are still multiple lastwritetime values being displayed. The If statement is seeing the much older write times and it is triggering the message-sending. This blows up my phone and negates the value of being messaged, as it is more often than not erroneous.    Here's the output from the code that you

Comment: TX029.7Z
Wednesday, September 13, 2017 11:44:54 AM
Tuesday, November 21, 2017 4:01:21 PM
Tuesday, November 21, 2017 4:45:44 PM
TX049.7Z
Tuesday, November 21, 2017 1:12:06 PM
Tuesday, November 21, 2017 4:45:54 PM
TX059.7Z
Tuesday, August 22, 2017 7:56:18 PM
Tuesday, November 21, 2017 4:03:39 PM
Tuesday, November 21, 2017 4:41:03 PM
TX013.7Z
Tuesday, November 21, 2017 4:01:21 PM
Monday, November 20, 2017 7:56:42 PM

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting 3 values for LastWriteTime as each file only has a single value. Can you please edit your post and add the exact function you are running and the output?